# Focus on error filed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I could have been in a search for this. Once the form is submitted , if the errors are available it shows on top as the validation summary (May be it will be done). Here is the critical. When i click on the error message, the focus should go to the corresponding error field. The field may be in the same tab or other tabs or other panels etc

Could it be possible to achieve?

Comment: It can be achieved. It all depends on how you've set up the form and the tabs.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code or any plunker url to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that would be to make the error message a label for that particular field:

```
<label for="myField">some error</label>
```

&

```
<input id="myField">
```

Clicking on the message would then automatically focus the field, no matter how far in the DOM the two elements are from each other.

---

An input can also be focused by JavaScript (see [.focus() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus)). In both cases, the input needs to actually be present in the DOM before it can be focused.

Comment: But the focus is not done if the controls are in different tabs. Can you advice on this? And also can we make on double click instead of single click on error message?

Comment: Ah, you mean in different browser tabs? That is a whole ballpark alltogether. I'm not sure whether that is possible at all and if it is, then with some heavy scripting. I'd suggest treating that as a design problem, not as a programming task (automated browser-tab-switching sounds like a very controversial design choice to me).

Comment: Focusing the field on double-click would need some JavaScript. As you haven't given any example of what solutions you've actually tried, I'm not going to go into that (you can Google it up).

Comment: Well tabs in the sense, html/jquery tabset not the browser tabs.

Comment: In that case, it would depend on the exact implementation. The input cannot be focused, if it's not actually in the DOM (which might be the case if it's on a "different tab"). In that case, you'd need to "switch to that tab" first (however that's done with your tabs) and then focus the element [by JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus).